# Converting Knitr to PDF

Tags: r, pdf, r-markdown, pandoc

I am trying to convert my knitr to a PDF.

Currently I have been trying the drop down menu in RStudio and selected Knit to PDF.

```
Error: pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found.
```

I have downloaded Pandoc here (pandoc-1.15.0.6-windows.msi):

https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/releases

I tried re-running it and the same problem keeps occurring. I am not sure if it is a directory issue or if I am just typing something wrong in but I am having major trouble with this.

Would someone be able to produce a reproducible example in how to type this into R.

Any help would be greatly appreciated and would save me big time. (By the way, I have no trouble with HTML, just PDF)

Thanks!

Comment: Do you have miktek or another TeX installed? `Note that PDF output (including Beamer slides) requires a full installation of TeX.`

Comment: I just have one miktek installed but it is under my downloads folder. Not sure where to place it directory-wise. And I do not have TeX installed. Should I do that? @jeremycg

Comment: Yes, install miktek (I'm assuming you are on windows).

Comment: @jeremycg yes I have Windows. Any idea what folder to save it to so that R can recognize it? I already have miktek installed and I am currently downloading TeX Live

Comment: Try and start a new session in R and then run knitr, that worked for me.